# The aesthetic education of man; translation

Tags: aesthetics

Can anyone recommend a good translation of *The Aesthetic Education of Man* by Friedrich Schiller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend :

On the Aesthetic Education of Man, ed. & tr. Elizabeth Wilkinson & L.A. Willoughby,
ISBN 10: 019815786X / ISBN 13: 9780198157861. Published by Oxford Univ Press, 1983.

It has a fairly massive introduction plus a commentary and glossary. It also prints the German and English texts on opposite pages, which means you are not totally in the translators' hands.

There is a new-ish Penguin translation which is reasonably scholarly:

On the Aesthetic Education of Man (Penguin Classics)
ISBN 10: 0141396962 / ISBN 13: 9780141396965
Published by Penguin Classics, 2016.